# how to find the last data in tableau?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

i want to find last data in tableau .

i used this code, but it doesn’t satisfy the results i want.

`[datatime]={FIXED:MAX([datatime])}`
and results just this
[image]

this is my data table
[image]

and i want the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some steps.

first of all you need to calculate the max date (Max Date) for each line and this something you can achieve twisting your Fixed formula, like this:

```
{ FIXED [line] : MAX([datetime])}
```

Then you need to create another calculated field (Check Max Date) to check this condition:

```
if [datetime] = [Max Date] then 'max' else 'other' end
```

Then you can use Check Max Date as a filter keeping just the 'max' values.

This is a quick example based on Sub-Categories from the Superstore sample dataset.

[image]